# Set Excel Worksheet Zoom Level from R (openxlsx)

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx, openxls

If I add a worksheet to an Excel workbook using `R` I am able to set its zoom level via:

```
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName="foo", zoom = "bar")
```

**But how do I set the zoom level to an existent sheet?**
openxlsx provides a similar option to row heights columns width:

```
openxlsx::setColWidths()
openxlsx::setRowHeights()
```

but I can't find the option for zoom level setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow we have not implemented a get/set function for `sheetViews`. The sheetViews xml string contains the zoom value:

```
"<sheetViews><sheetView workbookViewId=\"0\" zoomScale=\"100\" showGridLines=\"1\" tabSelected=\"1\"/></sheetViews>"
```

You can set it this way.

```r
# set zoom
set_zoom <- function(x) gsub('(?<=zoomScale=")[0-9]+', x, sV, perl = TRUE)

library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")

sV <- wb$worksheets[[1]]$sheetViews
wb$worksheets[[1]]$sheetViews <- set_zoom(75)

openXL(wb)
```

Comment: Much appreciated, @Jan. I thought I was missing that on the docs.